# 'history -s' in a script doesn't work

Tags: bash

I'm relatively new to linux, and trying furiously to lean bash, and eventually zsh. Anyway, for the moment this has me stumped:

```
#!/bin/bash
history -s "a_string"
```

.... doesn't work. I've tried a dozen variations on the idea, but nothing cuts it.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The subshell is not interactive, and therefore doesn't save the history **or** the parent shell doesn't reload history.

Typical ways around this:

1. use an alias instead of a script

   ```
      alias doit='history -s "a_string"'  
      unalias doit
   ```
2. use a shell function instead of script

   ```
      function doit() { 
           echo "A function is a lot like a script"
           history -s "but operates in a subshell only when a bash command does (piping)" 
      }
      unset doit
   ```
3. `source` the script, instead of executing it in a subshell

   ```
   source ./myscript.sh
   . ./myscript.sh   # equivalent shorthand for source
   ```

Comment: Thanks gentlemen, that gives me some insights into the problem.

Comment: Ok, I experimented with all of the above, and they all work, but the most useful for me is to use functions, not scripts.. I think that this is the first time I've _really_ understood the difference between the two.

Comment: Cheers. I fixed the formatting. You might actually be able to read what I intended now :)

Answer (score 1):

`$HISTFILE` and `$HISTFILESIZE` are not set when running a script like this. Once you set `$HISTFILE` you can read and write the history as you like.

Comment: and will the parent shell update the history _from_ that file after the script exits?

Comment: No. bash only automatically loads the history on startup, and saves on proper exit. For everything else there's `history`.

Comment: wouldn't it then _still_ not appear to work when the `history -s` is done Inside the script? Unless the script was sourced, it wouldn't affect the calling shell session?

Comment: The history would have to be written out in the script, and read in the calling session. Yes, there's no easy way to do that.