# Shell script not working while writing the same on the Terminal works

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I'm new to shell scripting and was reading online how shell scripts could be written.

I made this following script but it doesn't seem to work, but when I type this command directly in the terminal window then it works. Can someone please tell me why this is not working.

Thanks in advance.. Following is my script code

```
#!/bin/bash
history | grep " ls$" | cut -c 1-5 > /tmp/histDelTemp
```

But when I type

```
history | grep " ls$" | cut -c 1-5 > /tmp/histDelTemp
```

directly in the Terminal then it works correctly and generates the output in the /tmp/histDelTemp file.

Comment: yo run the script file and does not it give any output or you could not run the script

Comment: bash disables history tracking in non-interactive shells, and anyway the shell running the script would have a different history than the interactive shell you're running this from. Use a function instead of a script. This is a possible duplicate of [`history -s` in a script doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8116052/history-s-in-a-script-doesnt-work)